Export JSON to individual columns
I have a data.frame called df with the column revieweddata. In each row, there is a JSON structure with nested parts. I would like to unpack the information into individual columns, but for some reason, I'm unable.
JSON of the first row in column reiveweddata

  {
      "query": "Amazon Fresh Bestellungen sehen ",
      "response": "Klicke auf „Letzte Einkäufe“ auf der Amazon Fresh Startseite, um deine Bestellungen zu sehen.",
      "pills":
      [
          {
              "name": "Amazon Fresh",
              "link": "https://www.amazon.de/alm/storefront?almBrandId=QW1hem9uIEZyZXNo&ref=fs_dsk_sn_logo",
              "position": 37
          },
          {
              "name": "Letzte Einkäufe",
              "link": "https://www.amazon.de/afx/lists/pastpurchases/?almBrandId=QW1hem9uIEZyZXNo&ref=fs_dsk_sn_pastPurchases"
          }
      ]
  }

}


What I want are individual columns like: query, response, name1, link1, position1, name2, link2
Currently, I use this code:
# Upload csv file with raw data
df = pd.read_csv('raw_data.csv', encoding = 'utf8') 
df

# Define a function to extract information from JSON data
def extract_info(row):
    query = row['query']
    response = row['response']
    pills = row['pills']
    data = []
    for pill in pills:
        name = pill.get('name')
        link = pill.get('link')
        position = pill.get('position')
        data.append({'query': query, 'response': response, 'name': name, 'link': link, 'position': position})
    return data

# Apply the function to each row of the DataFrame
df['parsed_data'] = df['revieweddata'].apply(extract_info)

# Check if 'parsed_data' column exists
if 'parsed_data' in df.columns:
    # Create a new DataFrame from the 'parsed_data' column
    parsed_df = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('parsed_data').tolist())

    # Join the new DataFrame to the original DataFrame with a suffix
    df = df.join(parsed_df.add_suffix('_parsed'))

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)


This code should work but I permanently getting errors. Maybe someone could verify it for me.

One way of doing this is to use a function that will flatten any type of dataframe with nested fields (proposed here Converting JSON Dictionary to Dataframe). The advantage is that this can be used on any dataframe. Note that it is not specific to your dataframe, so, should it change over time, it will still work:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "revieweddata": [
        {
            "query": "Amazon Fresh Bestellungen sehen",
            "response": "Klicke auf „Letzte Einkäufe“ auf der Amazon Fresh Startseite, um deine Bestellungen zu sehen.",
            "pills": [
                {
                    "name": "Amazon Fresh",
                    "link": "https://www.amazon.de/alm/storefront?almBrandId=QW1hem9uIEZyZXNo&ref=fs_dsk_sn_logo",
                    "position": 37
                },
                {
                    "name": "Letzte Einkäufe",
                    "link": "https://www.amazon.de/afx/lists/pastpurchases/?almBrandId=QW1hem9uIEZyZXNo&ref=fs_dsk_sn_pastPurchases"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(exploded.columns)  # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            # print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df

Applied to you dataframe will return:
   index               revieweddata.query  \
0      0  Amazon Fresh Bestellungen sehen   
0      0  Amazon Fresh Bestellungen sehen   

                               revieweddata.response revieweddata.pills.name  \
0  Klicke auf „Letzte Einkäufe“ auf der Amazon Fr...            Amazon Fresh   
0  Klicke auf „Letzte Einkäufe“ auf der Amazon Fr...         Letzte Einkäufe   

                             revieweddata.pills.link  \
0  https://www.amazon.de/alm/storefront?almBrandI...   
0  https://www.amazon.de/afx/lists/pastpurchases/...   

   revieweddata.pills.position  
0                         37.0  
0                          NaN  

You can then rename your columns if you need to.
